# Will an ability to select identifier in designator based on the result of constant expression be useful?

Tags: c, initialization, language-lawyer, initializer

C11, 6.7.9 Initialization:

```
designator:
    [ constant-expression ]
    . identifier
```

Will an ability to select identifier in designator based on the result of constant expression be useful?

Rationale: if "a constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime" (6.6 Constant expressions), then its result can be used to provide an ability to select identifier in designator.

Example:

```
union
{
    float f;
    int   i;
} x = { <constant-expression> ? .f = 1.0f : .i = 0 };
```

It can be seen as: control the destination types based on the result of constant expression. Otherwise (now) the destination types (i.e. identifier in designator) need to be known in advance.

Comment: What are you even asking here? If your example is valid C? Or what's the purpose of `[ constant-expression ]` (note the brackets)? Or are you speculating in what manner of future language extensions that may be useful?

Comment: This is opinion-based, right?  The question seems to be "I have an extension to propose; is it a good idea?"

Comment: @Lundin Yes, it was an idea of future language extension. However, chux - Reinstate Monica has very nice solution. Hence, there is no need of such language extension.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, this is [opinion-based](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/201995/748373).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will an ability to select identifier in designator based on the result of constant expression be useful?

As code can already selectively initialize an object, I see little application to OP's new idea to selectively initialize a member.

```
typedef union {
  float f;
  int i;
} fi;

int main() {
  fi x = 0 ? (fi) {.f = 1.0f} : (fi) {.i = 0};
  printf("%f %d\n", x.f, x.i);
  fi y = 1 ? (fi) {.f = 1.0f} : (fi) {.i = 0};
  printf("%f %d\n", y.f, y.i);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0.000000 0
1.000000 1065353216
```

Answer (score 1):

I think OP got confused by what the standard say.

```
designator:
    [ constant-expression ]
    . identifier
```

is simply the definition of what is exemplify for instance in [6.7.9p35](https://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.7.9p35):

```
35   EXAMPLE 11 Designators can be used to provide explicit initialization when unadorned initializer lists
     might be misunderstood:
              struct { int a[3], b; } w[] =
                    { [0].a = {1}, [1].a[0] = 2 };
```

so here you have a variable `w` which is an array of struct, and `[0].a = {1}` initialize the field `a` of the first element of the array `w`.

so

```
union
{
    float f;
    int   i;
} x = { <constant-expression> ? .f = 1.0f : .i = 0 };
```

is currently invalid C